# Configuring ruamel.yaml to allow duplicate keys

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to use the `ruamel.yaml` library to process a Yaml document that contains duplicate keys. In this case the duplicate key happens to be a merge key `<<:`.

This is the yaml file, `dupe.yml`:

```
foo: &ref1
  a: 1

bar: &ref2
  b: 2

baz:
  <<: *ref1
  <<: *ref2
  c: 3
```

This is my script:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
doc = yml.load(open('dupe.yml'))

assert doc['baz']['a'] == 1
assert doc['baz']['b'] == 2
assert doc['baz']['c'] == 3
```

When run, it raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rua.py", line 5, in <module>
    yml.load(open('dupe.yml'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 331, in load
    return constructor.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 111, in get_single_data
    return self.construct_document(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 121, in construct_document
    for _dummy in generator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 1543, in construct_yaml_map
    self.construct_mapping(node, data, deep=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 1448, in construct_mapping
    value = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 174, in construct_object
    for _dummy in generator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 1543, in construct_yaml_map
    self.construct_mapping(node, data, deep=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 1399, in construct_mapping
    merge_map = self.flatten_mapping(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 1350, in flatten_mapping
    raise DuplicateKeyError(*args)
ruamel.yaml.constructor.DuplicateKeyError: while constructing a mapping
  in "dupe.yml", line 8, column 3
found duplicate key "<<"
  in "dupe.yml", line 9, column 3

To suppress this check see:
   http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#duplicate-keys

Duplicate keys will become an error in future releases, and are errors
by default when using the new API.
```

How can I make ruamel read this file without errors? The documentation says that `allow_duplicate_keys = True` will make the loader tolerate duplicated keys, but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using Python 3.7 and ruamel.yaml 0.15.90.

Comment: When using Python 3, I recommend you use `pathlib.Path` as parameter to load/dump: `yml.load(Path('dupe.yaml'))`. Also note that the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since Sep 2006.

Answer (score 3):

That

```
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
```

only works for non-merge keys in versions before 0.15.91.

In 0.15.91+ this works and the merge key assumes the value of the first instantiation of the key (like with non-merge keys), that means it works as if you had written:

```
baz:
  <<: *ref1
  c: 3
```

and **not** as if you had written:

```
baz:
  <<: [*ref1, *ref2]
  c: 3
```

If you need that you have to monkey-patch the flatten routine that handles the merge keys (and that affects loading of all following YAML files with double merge keys):

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
foo: &ref1
  a: 1

bar: &ref2
  b: 2

baz:
  <<: *ref1
  <<: *ref2
  c: 3

"""

def my_flatten_mapping(self, node):

    def constructed(value_node):
        # type: (Any) -> Any
        # If the contents of a merge are defined within the
        # merge marker, then they won't have been constructed
        # yet. But if they were already constructed, we need to use
        # the existing object.
        if value_node in self.constructed_objects:
            value = self.constructed_objects[value_node]
        else:
            value = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=False)
        return value

    merge_map_list = []
    index = 0
    while index < len(node.value):
        key_node, value_node = node.value[index]
        if key_node.tag == u'tag:yaml.org,2002:merge':
            if merge_map_list and not self.allow_duplicate_keys:  # double << key
                args = [
                    'while constructing a mapping',
                    node.start_mark,
                    'found duplicate key "{}"'.format(key_node.value),
                    key_node.start_mark,
                    """
                    To suppress this check see:
                       http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#duplicate-keys
                    """,
                    """\
                    Duplicate keys will become an error in future releases, and are errors
                    by default when using the new API.
                    """,
                ]
                if self.allow_duplicate_keys is None:
                    warnings.warn(DuplicateKeyFutureWarning(*args))
                else:
                    raise DuplicateKeyError(*args)
            del node.value[index]
            # if key/values from later merge keys have preference you need
            # to insert value_node(s) at the beginning of merge_map_list
            # instead of appending
            if isinstance(value_node, ruamel.yaml.nodes.MappingNode):
                merge_map_list.append((index, constructed(value_node)))
            elif isinstance(value_node, ruamel.yaml.nodes.SequenceNode):
                for subnode in value_node.value:
                    if not isinstance(subnode, ruamel.yaml.nodes.MappingNode):
                        raise ruamel.yaml.constructor.ConstructorError(
                            'while constructing a mapping',
                            node.start_mark,
                            'expected a mapping for merging, but found %s' % subnode.id,
                            subnode.start_mark,
                        )
                    merge_map_list.append((index, constructed(subnode)))
            else:
                raise ConstructorError(
                    'while constructing a mapping',
                    node.start_mark,
                    'expected a mapping or list of mappings for merging, '
                    'but found %s' % value_node.id,
                    value_node.start_mark,
                )
        elif key_node.tag == u'tag:yaml.org,2002:value':
            key_node.tag = u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str'
            index += 1
        else:
            index += 1
    return merge_map_list

ruamel.yaml.constructor.RoundTripConstructor.flatten_mapping = my_flatten_mapping

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
for k in data['baz']:
    print(k, '>', data['baz'][k])
```

The above gives:

```
c > 3
a > 1
b > 2
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized the original question was ambiguous, so I've updated it to clarify that the behavior I'm seeking is that of your second snippet: basically combining the duplicated merge keys into one.

Comment: @mamacdon I would really like to know what program created that kind of crappy YAML to begin with. I can update my answer, but from your example it is unclear which value has precedence (`[*ref1, *ref2]` differs from `[*ref2, *ref1]` in case the anchored mappings have keys in common, but with differing values. What  version do you need (let me know if you don't understand the difference)?

Comment: The YAML was handwritten. It came from a configuration file used in our team's Concourse CI pipeline. I don't know what version of YAML it is. Concourse CI appears to be using the library `gopkg.in/yaml.v2` as its parser. So we would've been developing against whatever inputs that library allows.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the library source code, I found a workaround. Setting the option to `None` prevents the error.

```
yml.allow_duplicate_keys = None
```

A warning is still printed to the console, but it's not fatal and the program will continue.