# ruamel.yaml dump explicit/dereferenced data

Tags: python, yaml

Using `ruamel.yaml`, how to (1) produce exactly the same input (same order, comments, references, aliases, anchor) and (2) how to produce a dereferenced values?

For instance, given the following code

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_input = """\
shape: &shape
  color: blue

square: &square
  a: 5

rectangle:
  <<: *shape
  <<: *square
  b: 3
  color: green
"""
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_input)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Its output is

```yaml
shape: &shape
  color: blue

square:
  a: 5

rectangle:
  <<: *shape
  b: 3
  color: green
```

1. How to produce a dereferenced output, like

```yaml
shape:
  color: blue

square:
  a: 5

rectangle:
  b: 3
  a: 5
  color: green
```

2. How to produce the same output as the input itself (with implicit data, that is without dereferenceing values), lile

```yaml
shape: &shape
  color: blue

square: &square
  a: 5

rectangle:
  <<: *shape
  <<: *square
  b: 3
  color: green
```

Comment: A construction with *several* `<<` keys is not well-defined in YAML specification. If you want to combine several maps, then use `<<: [*shape, *square]`, as described in the [spec](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html). In other question the author or ruamel [describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55542424/3440745), that given package interprets duplicate keys using a "win first" strategy.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks. Using `<<: [*shape, *square]` has zero affect in the snippet above. That is, it does not change the result.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It is actually an error to have a mapping with a key that occurs twice. Some libraries make the error of ignoring that. Usually you get the second value (i.e by overwriting the first). But the handling `<<` in e.g. PyYAML has more of an update semantics which just happens to make it behave like the correct semantics  you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Having duplicate keys in a mapping is not allowed in YAML. There are however YAML libraries that ignore this,
including PyYAML. Historically, in `ruamel.yaml`, throwing an error on a duplicate key
was added first (including explicitly allowing duplicate keys), and preserving merge keys later on.
But the preservation of merge keys expects correct YAML (it would be nice if `ruamel.yaml` throws
an error when encountering duplicate merge keys when `.allow_duplicate_keys` is set, but it doesn't)

Since there is no mechanism built into
`ruamel.yaml` to process these in round-trip mode, you have to use:

```
<<: [*shape, *square]
```

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
shape: &shape
  color: blue

square: &square
  a: 5

rectangle:
  <<: [*shape, *square]
  b: 3
  color: green
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives the same outut as the input:

```
shape: &shape
  color: blue

square: &square
  a: 5

rectangle:
  <<: [*shape, *square]
  b: 3
  color: green
```

Internally `ruamel.yaml`, gives you a dict like type that contains a list of the dicts of the merged mappings, so that
you can do:

```
print(data['rectangle']['a'])
```

and expect to see `5` printed. It does so by looking up 'a' in the dicts pointed to when not found in the main dict.
But if you assign to  `data['rectangle']['a']`, the value for key `a` is set, whether the key was already there or not:

```
data['rectangle']['a'] = data['rectangle']['a']
```

will dump with `a: 5` at the bottom (and of course still as part of `square` as well).

That means you can do:

```py
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
rectangle = data['rectangle']
for k, v in rectangle.items():
    rectangle[k] = v
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

and get:

```
shape: &shape
  color: blue

square: &square
  a: 5

rectangle:
  <<: [*shape, *square]
  b: 3
  color: green
  a: 5
```

and if you want to get rid of the merge keys, it is easiest you create a new `dict`:

```py
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
rectangle = data['rectangle']
new_rectangle = {}
for k, v in rectangle.items():
    new_rectangle[k] = v
data['rectangle'] = new_rectangle
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

and get:

```
shape:
  color: blue

square:
  a: 5

rectangle:
  b: 3
  color: green
  a: 5
```